# Is there a way to initialize a 3D matrix in Stata?

Tags: stata

In MATLAB (and many other similar languages), we can construct such a matrix with

```
mat = zeros(A,B,C)
```

It does not appear that there is such a convenience constructor in Stata [J(.,.,.) appears to only construct 2D matrices]. Is there any way to construct a 3D matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly a matrix is two-dimensional, or one-dimensional as a special case. But we know what you mean.

Mata supports associative arrays.

In Stata, people would be more likely to set up a data structure with several variables as row identifier, column identifier, layer identifier, whatever, whatever else, and so on.

Comment: Could you provide a trivial example of the Stata data structure you mention? Or a link to such?

Comment: It's no more and no less than what `contract` or `collapse` would produce.  In terms of datasets rather than results sets, many people work with trade data indexed by importer, exporter, time.